# Last positive element per row in a Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab

I would like to find the last positive element per row in a matrix `X` of dimension `wxy` in Matlab.

```
rng default;  

%if w=1, then the code below works
A=sort(randn(1,20), 'descend');
idx=find(A>=0, 1, 'last');

%if w>1, how can I proceed?
A=sort(randn(8000,20),2, 'descend');
%idx=?
%I am expecting idx=[12;5;8;...]
```

Could you help me with a very efficient code?

Comment: Would your input array be sorted as shown in the sample input `A`?

Comment: Yes, it is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rng default;  

A=sort(randn(8000,20),2, 'descend');
idx = sum(A>=0, 2);
```

Actually you don't need to sort.

```
A = randn(8000,20);
idx = sum(A>=0, 2);
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted the comment when I realized you were sorting.  But I don't understand why you say you don't need to sort.  In the counterexample `A=[1,-1,1]` the unsorted approach returns 2 but the correct answer is 3.

Comment: Equivalently he is counting how many positive numbers in each row.

Comment: True if the OP only wants the count of positive numbers, but the title suggests that he/she might want the value itself.

Comment: I don't need the value but just the position.

Comment: @user299158 Then it's what I said. You are effectively counting the number of above-zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to your title is harder than the answer to your specific case.  In your example you seem to be asking for the "last positive element per row in a Matlab matrix **in which each row is sorted in descending order**".  This is equivalent to asking for "the smallest positive value in each row" which can be accomplished without sorting:

```
function [val, ind] = smallest_positive(A, dim)

if nargin < 2, A = A(:); dim = 1; end
A(A <= 0) = inf;
[val, ind] = min(A, [], dim);
```

Example of use:

```
>> A = randn(3, 8)

A =

    0.7990    0.2120   -0.7420    0.3899   -0.5596    0.7812   -0.2656    0.9863
    0.9409    0.2379    1.0823    0.0880    0.4437    0.5690   -1.1878   -0.5186
   -0.9921   -1.0078   -0.1315   -0.6355   -0.9499   -0.8217   -2.2023    0.3274

>> [val, ind] = smallest_positive(A, 2)

val =

    0.2120
    0.0880
    0.3274


ind =

     2
     4
     8
```

Note that this returns the "last" positive value on each row only in the sense of "the value that would be last if you were to do the `sort`".   If you literally want the last positive value on each row, whether sorted or not, then Divakar's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution I can think of (given `A` is sorted):

```
[~,idx] = min(A>=0,[],2);   % Returns the first indices of the zero entries
idx = idx-1;               % Get the indices before the first zero entries
```

Comment: This is the most efficient (and most golfed) solution I can imagine. It's worth pointing out that  `A` *must* have the characteristic that each row is sorted in descending order (which is true for the OP's two examples).

Comment: @jez I clarified that `A` must be sorted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Richard Should I use `A>=0` to be consistent with my example with `w=1`?

Comment: @user299158 Yes, sorry that was my mistake. I changed it in the answer. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question title I am solving for a generic case and making no assumption about the inputs being sorted or otherwise.

The idea here is to flip the rows and compare against `zero` and then get `argmax` along each row and then compensate for the flipping by subtracting from row length -

```
[~,idx] = max(a(:,end:-1:1)>=0,[],2);
out = size(a,2) - idx + 1
```

To get the corresponding elements, simply get the linear indices and index -

```
a_last = a((out-1)*size(a,1) + [1:size(a,1)]')
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
    1.6110    0.0854   -0.8777    0.6078    0.0544   -0.4089    0.0675
    0.7708    1.6510    0.1572   -0.7475    0.0218   -0.8292    1.0934
   -0.4704    1.2351    1.2660    2.2117   -0.3616   -0.9500   -0.7682
    0.8539   -0.5427   -1.0213    0.2489   -1.6312    0.0723    0.1284
    1.5050    1.4430    1.1947    0.2846   -1.2621    0.5518    1.4290
    0.1785    1.1087   -0.0225    1.1447    0.2316   -0.2431   -1.2750
    0.3089    1.5716   -1.9958    0.0015    1.5448   -0.0750    0.4965
    0.3593    0.8143    0.4389   -0.2541    0.1558   -0.2965    0.7111
>> [~,idx] = max(a(:,end:-1:1)>=0,[],2);
>> out = size(a,2) - idx + 1
out =
     7
     7
     4
     7
     7
     5
     7
     7
>> a((out-1)*size(a,1) + [1:size(a,1)]')
ans =
    0.0675
    1.0934
    2.2117
    0.1284
    1.4290
    0.2316
    0.4965
    0.7111
```